# How to parallelize Greedy assignment problem

Tags: python, multiprocessing, multicore, hungarian-algorithm

I have a large 2D **cost** matrix: 500K x 500K and I want to solve the assignment problem. Aside from the Hungarian algorithm, I want to use below greedy algorithm to reduce the time:

```
# H1,H2 in range(500K)
for n1 in H1:
    best = -1
    for n2 in H2:
        if cost[n1,n2] > best and n2 not in matched:
            aligned[n1]=n2
            best = cost[n1,n2]
    matched.append(aligned[n1])
```

Using one core it will take forever (for 5Kx5K it takes 40mins on single thread). I guess we cannot parallelize the nested loop, because we need the **best** variable. right?
I tried this code to parallelize, but it gives me many repetitive columns.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

inputs = range(500000)
def processInput(i):
    row = cost[i, :]
    # cost[row, col[0][0]] = 10e5 ### not possible as read-only in multiprocessing
    return i,col


num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
row_col = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(processInput)(i) for i in inputs)
```

any suggestion to run the greedy algorithm faster (my parallel solution is not working)?

Comment: Is it worth mentioning what non-standard package `Parallel` and `delayed` come from?

Comment: @Booboo sure I did

Comment: https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ is the documentation for `Parallel` and `delayed` come form.

Comment: @PaulBrennan Was that a response to me or to @Booboo?
If for me, I do not know how to use your provided documentation to take care of a shared variable (best variable here not to select columns selected before)

Comment: it was for everyone else so they don't have to look it up...